# Multiple file upload using prototype.js

Tags: ajax, prototypejs

Is there a way to upload file using pure prototype and ajax. I've searched for it on google but did't got any satisfactory result. Can anyone please help me out??

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to get an "Ajax" file upload to work is to use a keyhole iframe as the target for your form:

```
<form action="handler/url" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="keyhole" method="post">
    <input type="file" multiple name="user_file[]" />
    <input type="submit" id="upload" value="Upload">
</form>
<!-- style the following to be tiny/hidden -->
<iframe id="keyhole" src="about:blank"></iframe>
```

The trick with this is to show a waiting indicator, and hide it after the upload is complete.

```
<div id="waiting" style="display:none"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('upload').observe('click', function(evt){
        $('waiting').show();
    });
</script>
```

In your file upload handler, return a text/javascript header and the following script after a successful upload:

```
var waiting = top.document.getElementById('waiting');
if(waiting) waiting.style.display = 'none';
```

Naturally, this will only work if both endpoints are on the same server, owing to Same Origin Policy.

Comment: I like this approach, but what do you mean to "return a text/javascript header" exactly?  Do you return content of type "text/javascript" or do you mean to return a blank html response with the javascript written out within a <script> element?

Comment: It depends on your server. In PHP, you would use `header('Content-type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8');` followed by the literal text of the script. In Rails, you would just ensure that your request ended in .js and you would get the desired header for free.

Comment: OK, I'll have to see how .NET and my client-side library (PrototypeJS) will behave with this.  Thanks for the follow up.